# How to remove unexpected dot from the file name in php

Tags: php

I have the code through which i am uploading the image and before storing it, the image name is randomly generated and also the image is compressed. But there is small problem, when i am uploading image having dot(.) like a.k.kumar.jpg , the image is not uploading and showing the error according to code i.e. Invalid File Type. I just want to upload image with a.k.kumar.jpg name also.

Here is my php code:

```
  $banner = "SELECT * FROM inventory_details where firm_email='$firm_email'";
  $resultp5 = mysqli_query($conn, $banner);
  mysqli_num_rows($resultp5) > 0;
  $rowp5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultp5);

  if(!empty($_FILES['banner'] ['name'])){ 
        $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['banner'] ['name']);
        $banner = rand(10000,99999) . '.' . $extension[1];
        $valid_ext = array('png','jpeg','jpg');
        $location = "image/banner/".$banner;
        $file_extension = pathinfo($location, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if(in_array($file_extension,$valid_ext)){  
            compressImage($_FILES['banner']['tmp_name'],$location,60);
        }else{
            echo "Invalid file type.";
        }
  } 
  else{
    $banner=$rowp5['banner'];
  }
```

I have also tried this but not helpful:

```
 $banner = "SELECT * FROM inventory_details where firm_email='$firm_email'";
  $resultp5 = mysqli_query($conn, $banner);
  mysqli_num_rows($resultp5) > 0;
  $rowp5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultp5);

  if(!empty($_FILES['banner'] ['name'])){ 
        $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['banner'] ['name']);
        $banner = rand(10000,99999) . '.' . $extension[1];
        $valid_ext = array('png','jpeg','jpg');


        $lastDot = strrpos($valid_ext, ".");
        $valid_ext = str_replace(".", "", substr($valid_ext, 0, $lastDot)) . substr($valid_ext, $lastDot);


        $location = "image/banner/".$banner;
        $file_extension = pathinfo($location, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if(in_array($file_extension,$valid_ext)){  
            compressImage($_FILES['banner']['tmp_name'],$location,60);
        }else{
            echo "Invalid file type.";
        }
  } 
  else{
    $banner=$rowp5['banner'];
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes,but not helpful

Comment: check my update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of relying on `explode` to determine the `extension` you could resort to [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) e.g.

```
  $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['banner'] ['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

---

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_FILES['banner'] ['name'])) {
        $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['banner'] ['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $banner = rand(10000,99999) . '.' . $extension;
        $location = "image/banner/".$banner;

        if(in_array(strtolower($extension), [ 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', ])){
            compressImage($_FILES['banner']['tmp_name'],$location,60);
        }else{
            echo "Invalid file type.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is another thing and it is showing some other error

Comment: U would need to replace the `explode` just below your `if(!empty($_FILES['b...`

Comment: yes dude, i replace the same and the image is not uploading and it shows the error Invalid fie type